# Circular Subarray Sum

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am solving [maximum circular subarray sum](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/max-circular-subarray-sum-1587115620/1#) i tried to come up with slightly different approach.

I have created new array with size double of original array.
Original array - [8 -8 9 -9 10 -11 12]
New array - [8 -8 9 -9 10 -11 12 8 -8 9 -9 10 -11 12 ]

I have applied Kadane's algorithm on new array in order to find circular subarray sum by converting original circular array to linear data structure.

Can anybody tell where i am going wrong?

Code :-

```
 static int circularSubarraySum(int a[], int n) {
 
       int[] arr = new int[2*n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            arr[i] = a[i];
        
        for(int i=n;i<2*n;i++)
            arr[i] = a[i-n];
            
         for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
            System.out.println();
        //now apply kadans algorithm
        int current = 0,max = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            {
                current += arr[i];
                if(max<current)
                    max = current;
                if(current<0)
                    current = 0;
            }
            return max;
    }
```

Comment: You didn't limit the length of the subarray. The chosen subarray must not be longer than the original array.

Comment: Yes, i realized that later, thank you.